# Sass/Compass tutorial for Zen?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to understand sass and compass so that I can take advantage of them when subtheming Zen, but I'm having trouble finding a good tutorial.

All of the documentation I find seems to already expect me to understand what the heck they are talking about. :) I've got a full understanding of standard CSS, that's not the issue.

I'm trying to do just the simplest thing and I'm not sure what the next step is. For example, by default the max-width is 1200 in the sass/layouts/responsive-sidebars.scss. I would like to change it, but when I make changes to responsive-sidebars.scss nothing in my actual presentation changes (I'm assuming because the actual presentation is using the actual css files in css/layouts/responsive-sidebars.css).

What am I missing? Do I need to do something to actively translate the scss file into the css in the other directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I finally found this documentation on how to get started and how to automatically convert the scss files into css files:

http://drupal.org/node/1548946